# Converting excel file to time series format

Tags: r

I have a data in excel with 13 columns defined as year and months. I want to run time series analysis but finds it difficult to plot the data. Please how can I convert this file such that I can analyse the data?
[My excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qz0B.jpg)

Tried plotting but gets error. Error reads "can not plot morethan 10 series"

Answer (score 0):

Say your data is `df`.

Using base `R`,

```
rownames(df) <- df$Year
df$Year <- NULL
  
ts(as.vector(t(as.matrix(dummy.df))), 
   start=..., end=..., frequency=12)
```

You may change `start` and `end` depends on your data.